# How to read the web.xml from a WebApp

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, glassfish

For WebApps, web.xml can be used to store application settings. How can I read this file. My servlets run in a GlassFish v2 server.

Comment: Perhaps you could post an example code snippet of what you are trying to do?

Comment: I want to read some custom settings. First I tried a properties-file, but I can't determine the path to the file (it's not in `System.getProperty("user.dir")`).

Answer (score 9):

Not sure I fully understand this question...

Assuming your Servlet extends [`HttpServlet`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/index.html)?

`HttpServlet` implements `ServletConfig`, so you can find out servlet specific parameters using:

In web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-class>com.acme.Foo</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>my.init.param</param-name>
        <param-value>10</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

In servlet:

```
int x = Integer.parseInt(getInitParameter("my.init.param"));
```

Similarly, you can get global (context-wide) settings using:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>my.context.param</param-name>
    <param-value>Hello World</param-value>
</context-param>
```

In servlet:

```
String s = getServletContext.getInitParameter("my.context.param");
```

Of course, if you're using a framework along with your servlets, such as Spring, then you can use Spring's configuration files instead to inject settings into your web-app classes.

Comment: Looks great. But which `getServletContext` do I need? See next comment.

Comment: javax.servlet.FilterConfig,javax.servlet.GenericServlet,javax.servlet.http.HttpSession,javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext,javax.servlet.ServletConfig,javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent,javax.servlet.ServletRequestEvent or javax.xml.rpc.server.ServletEndpointContext?

Comment: You call getServletContext() in the Servlet, so you'll get an implementation of javax.servlet.ServletContext.

Comment: is it required to extend HttpServlet? Is there no static method?

Comment: You need to also add <servlet-name>...</servlet-name> tag otherwise it may not work

Answer (score 2):

Add an init-param:

```
<init-param> 
    <param-name>InitParam</param-name> 
    <param-value>init param value</param-value> 
</init-param>
```

Then read it from java code (within a servlet):

```
String initParam = getServletConfig().getInitParameter("InitParam");
```

Answer (score 0):

Doekman, is it possible to explain why you want to read the web.xml file? The settings in this file are targeted to the WebContainer. If you want to pass configuration parameters to be loaded by your application, then just use Context Parameters:

[*The optional context-param element declares a Web Application's servlet context initialization parameters. You set each context-param within a single context-param element, using  and  elements. You can access these parameters in your code using the javax.servlet.ServletContext.getInitParameter() and javax.servlet.ServletContext.getInitParameterNames() methods.*](http://edocs.bea.com/wls/docs61/webapp/web_xml.html#1014756)

If you really needs to read the file, then I'm pretty sure you can try to load the file using Java IO. The only thing you need to know is the working path used by Glassfish when your application is running. You could try something like this System.getProperty("user.dir");

From there you can load the file using a relative path. Examples on [www.exampledepot.com](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/ReadLinesFromFile.html).

Comment: I tried property-files, but I couldn't determine the relative path. My webservices are running within GlassFish v2.

Answer (score 0):

The choice of container shouldn't be relevant to this question, as each container should implement the [servlet container](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servlet_container) specification, be it Tomcat, Glassfish or one of the [many others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Servlet_containers).