# How To Read Context Parameters From a Restlet?

Tags: java, servlets, restlet

When using [Restlets](http://restlet.org), how can I read configuration parameters passed in through web.xml? With servlets, [context-param](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520467/how-to-read-the-web-xml-from-a-webapp) can be used. How do I read context parameters from within a Restlet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [mailing list](http://restlet.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4447&dsMessageId=12792):

> the init parameters are available in the [application's context](http://www.restlet.org/documentation/1.1/ext/com/noelios/restlet/ext/servlet/ServerServlet.html):
>   getApplication().get​Context().getParamet​ers().

In web.xml:

```
  <context-param>
    <param-name>my.context.param</param-name>
    <param-value>Hello World</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

In a Restlet's represent method, use:

```
// => "Hello World"
String result = 
  getApplication().getContext().getParameters().getFirstValue("my.context.param");
```

Answer (score 1):

`ServerServlet` adds all the init parameters from both the `servletConfig` and from the `servletContext` to the application context.

So depending on your need, you could either examine the source code for `ServerServlet`, and read the configuration parameters in the same way, or simply obtain the values from your restlet, or your restlet's application's context.