# How to check web.xml configuration during runtime?

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, web.xml, servlet-filters

I have a [Java EE Interceptor](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkigq.html) in which I need to check whether a particular [filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnagb.html) is a part of current web.xml configuration or not. Then how can I do that in runtime?

Comment: Why would you want to access filter information from ejb interceptor? Mising business layer and frontend concept, oops

Comment: I think this post [How to read the web-xml from a webapp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520467/how-to-read-the-web-xml-from-a-webapp) maybe help you.

Answer (score 2):

I do not fully understand your requirement since EJBs (Interceptors) and Servlets are two different parts.

To access the Servlet configuration, which contain the filters. You can use these:

ServletContext#getFilterRegistrations()

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getFilterRegistrations%28%29

and ServletConfig

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletConfig.html